Unable to retrieve the IP address of the client for kubernetes application
I have a Spring Cloud Gateway application. I deployed it on Azure Kubernetes. So it runs in a pod.
When I try to retrieve the IP address of the client it returns an IP starting with 10*.x.x.x and it doesn't even belong to gateway pod.
Here is my k8s file.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api-gateway
          image: xxx/api-gateway:1.0.0
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "500Mi"
            requests:
              memory: "300Mi"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: JWT_BASE64_URL_ENCODED
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secrets
                  key: jwt-base64-encode
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: api-gateway
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

And my code to retrieve IP address.

@Component
public class ClientIpFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

     var resolver = XForwardedRemoteAddressResolver.maxTrustedIndex(1);

     var clientAddress = resolver.resolve(exchange);

         if (clientAddress != null) { 
          // Client Address: /10.224.0.4:39303
        }

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}


When I run the code above it just prints 10.224.0.4:39303 and that's not my IP so client.

Typically you will see the ip address of the Kubernetes ingress servers. It is common for most such services to provide the real client ip as a HTTP header (often X-Forwarded-For). Take a look at the headers of an incoming request and see what you find.
